# One Field is not getting saved to the database, always returns as 0.0

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Im trying to save product entity in postgres table, and if i send request from postman, it returns sved object, but MRP field is always 0.0

Entity class:

```
package com.acms.models;

import java.time.Instant;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "productid")
    private String productId;
    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private long timeStamp;
    private String description;
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "mrp")
    private double mRP;
    private int quantity;
    private double promotion;

    public Product() {
        super();
        long epochTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
        this.timeStamp = epochTime;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getMRP() {
        return mRP;
    }

    public void setMRP(double mRP) {
        this.mRP = mRP;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getPromotion() {
        return promotion;
    }

    public void setPromotion(double promotion) {
        this.promotion = promotion;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [productId=" + productId + ", timeStamp=" + timeStamp + ", description=" + description
                + ", name=" + name + ", MRP=" + mRP + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", promotion=" + promotion + "]";
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/product/save")
    public Product postDataToProductTable(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return this.productService.postDataToProductTable(product);
    }
```

Service:

```
public Product postDataToProductTable(Product product) {
        return this.productRepository.save(product);
    }
```

Request sent with url and object:

```
http://localhost:8080/product/save
{
    "productId":"p106",
    "description":"butter",
    "name":"amul",
    "mRP":"200",
    "quantity":"8",
    "promotion":"5.0"
}
```

Object returned:

```
{
    "productId": "p106",
    "description": "butter",
    "name": "amul",
    "quantity": 8,
    "promotion": 5.0,
    "mrp": 0.0
}
```

notice how above, the mrp is returned as 0.0, but all other fields are fine.

Table in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    serialNumber SERIAL,
    productID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    timeStamp bigint NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(50),
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    MRP NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    quantity int NOT NULL,
    promotion NUMERIC,
    PRIMARY KEY(productID),
    UNIQUE(productID, timeStamp)
);
```

Comment: Is it 0.0 in the database as well?

Comment: yes, its getting saved as default value i think, i dont know why its not mapping to mRP

Comment: I think it is beacuse the annotation say column name `mrp` (lover case) the database says `MRP´ aupper case).

Comment: change @Column(name = "mrp") to @Column(name = "MRP")

Comment: no, postgres converts everything to lowercase, even if i change mrp to MRP in the entity class, it still returning 0 and entering 0 in database.

Comment: according to that, shouldn't @Column(name = "productid") be @Column(name = "productId")  ? that is saving fine,

Comment: @MadhumitaGangaS, Can you print your product object before calling the same method and see if values are properly set to the object.

Comment: Product [productId=p110, timeStamp=1588426591, description=butter, name=amul, MRP=0.0, quantity=8, promotion=5.0]

Comment: i printed it and this is what came.

Comment: Use proper type with column definition see here https://www.service-architecture.com/articles/database/mapping_sql_and_java_data_types.html

Comment: @Eklavya then how come promotion is working?

Comment: Im very new to spring, jpa,hibernate and postgres.

Comment: 1) Can you send mRP as 200.00 and see if any luck and also tryy changing mRP variable to mrp and see, I am suspecting while setting mrp value it couldn't find appropriate setter method

Comment: which one worked??

Comment: changed mRP to mrp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly because your JSON request sends mRP as a String type, but in your model it's defined as a `double`. Lose the `""` around mRP's value in the JSON request and see if that helps.

Another option is that you defined this type as `numeric` in the database, but in the model it's a `double`. In my experience I would prefer to use a `BigDecimal` to map to a `numeric` field in postgres. But if it must be a `double` in your model then why not use that as a type in the database as well? Not everything that can be saved in a `numeric` field can actually be represented in a Java `double`.

Postgres data types: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html

Also (from comments discussion) inconsistent casing between the Json and the field name in the model and could be causing issues if using Spring Data JPA/Spring MVC.

Comment: doesn't help :/

Comment: How come promotion is working, then? that is also numeric and double.

Comment: @MadhumitaGangaS you're right, that is strange. Still I would recommend choosing the recomended data types.
If that doesn't help, you should turn on sql logging, in particular set the `org.hibernate.SQL` lognode to `debug`, it should show you which updates and which queries are being done for this request.

Comment: i displayed the object before calling save, Product [productId=p110, timeStamp=1588426591, description=butter, name=amul, MRP=0.0, quantity=8, promotion=5.0]

Comment: @MadhumitaGangaS Ok, so it's not even set on insertion. I would try to use a consistent spelling/casing of MRP, because now it's sometimes uppercased, sometimes lowercased and then in the json it only has the m lowercase. That might be an issue for Spring Data JPA.

Comment: its not saving in the object also

Comment: @MadhumitaGangaS ok so what if the field is called `mrp` or `MRP` in the JSON? Still the same result?

Comment: changed mRP to mrp and now its working! no clue why it didnt work before.

Comment: Probably the Jackson objectmapper that Spring MVC uses to map the JSON to the model is case sensitive. There are probably some settings you could tweak for that, although I wouldn't touch it myself.